# How to make beautiful soup 4 work when it's headless?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this code and this successfully scrapes links from a ddg search

```
options = Options()
options.headless = False
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

def ddg(query):
    browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
    search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    html = browser.page_source

    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(query + Keys.RETURN)

    while page_counter < page_count_total:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.result--more__btn"))).click()
            page_counter += 1
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more More Results button")
            break
        
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        xpath_string = "//*[@id="+"rld"+"-"+str(page_counter)+"]/a"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    for text in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'result__a'}):
        href = text.get('href')
        links.append(href)
```

I made one change and that it I switched it from `options.headless = False` to `options.headless = True` and the code no longer works. I'd like to be able to run this code without having the window for Chrome pop up on my machine.

Can beautiful soup work in the case where the headless option is set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all links from DDG with only BeautifulSoup (not using selenium) by using non Javascript version of DDG on URL `'https://duckduckgo.com/html/'`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def ddg(query):
    url = 'https://duckduckgo.com/html/'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params={'q':query}, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

    while True:
        for a in soup.select('.result__a'):
            yield a['href']

        f = soup.select_one('input[value="Next"]')
        if not f:
            break

        params = {i['name']: i.get('value', '') for i in f.find_parent('form').select('input[name]')}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')


for result in ddg('python'):
    print(result)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.python.org/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
https://www.techbeamers.com/python-tutorial-step-by-step/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm
https://github.com/python/cpython
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU
https://pythonprogramming.net/
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp
https://devopedia.org/python
https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/
http://pythonnet.github.io/
https://brython.info/

...and so on.
```

Comment: @Cauder I don't use `selenium` because it's too heavyweight for my tasks, but I could imagine when headless mode is set to `True` javascript inside the page is run a little bit differently. However, this needs more debugging.